# Does gorgeous carry a sexual connotation?

Tags: meaning, connotations

From dictionaries, gorgeous means

- *very beautiful* ([macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gorgeous))
- *Beautiful; very attractive* ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gorgeous))

But I wonder if calling someone gorgeous, as in  *she is gorgeous*, means beautiful in a sexual way. Does it ?

Comment: Consider telling your wife your secretary is gorgeous & anticipate the response ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin  I am neither married nor British

Comment: nor, presumably, still living in the 1950s - but I'm sure you get my point ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no implied sexual connotation.

If it did, I'd have been offended when my father called me gorgeous on my wedding day. That would be creepy.

It would also be inappropriate to use the word in relation to non-human things but it's used often in reference to both animate and inanimate objects:

- [Gorgeous House](http://www.vrbo.com/483386)
- [Dogs](https://www.tumblr.com/tagged/gorgeous-dog)
- [Fabric](https://gorgeousfabrics.com/)

You can be attracted to something without wanting to sleep with it.

Comment: Your last sentence is remarkable. But comparing with the other answer, i m in a dilemma whether to accept yours or the other one

Comment: @MAKZ It's recommended to not accept answers quickly for exactly that reason.  Give it a day and let other people upvote answers and that will tell you which is more accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: You're right, but I'd still recommend caution when using this word. What's appropriate between a father and his daughter on her wedding day might not be appropriate between co-workers at the office water cooler. The word can indeed be used in a non-sexual way, but there are better alternatives in a professional environment, like _nice_ or _sharp_.

Comment: @J.R. Maybe the question should address the environment the OP is using it, then?

Comment: @Catija - That would probably help, but I think it's an interesting question as is. I think gorgeous _can_ carry a hint of sexual connotation, but not necessarily always. It's good for the learner to know both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not in quite the same was as, for instance, "hot". "Attractive" and "beautiful", at least when applied to adult women by men, should be assumed to have a sexual component. So "gorgeous" has such an implication. However, it also often has a connotation of "intimidatingly beautiful", and nothing interferes with men's libido like intimidation.

Answer (score -1):

I would say it does, but I think it's not clear-cut and depends on the speaker.  It sounds to me that it literally means that I want to gorge myself on the subject, which is definitely sexual.